# I have a web design error when I test my project under internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, grails

I have a grails application. When I finish the web design of this project, I try to test it under more than one browser such that Opera, Firefox, and Google Chrome. It works fine on these browser, but when I try to load this project under Internet Explorer it return an empty page without and style or design.

Does someone know what is the problem.

Comment: What version of IE are you testing in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the doctype and IE is less permissive. Put this at the beginning of the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a doctype above it

and replacing the head tag

Replace

```
<html>
```

with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: You do not replace the `<head>` tag, you replace the `<html>` tag. Also you could just use `<!doctype html>` for HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

The page is rendering in quirks mode - you can check this by opening the Developer Tools (F12) and checking the Document Mode at the end of the menu bar. Change this to IE8 Standards and the content is visible. Add a Doctype to your HTML.